# The description for Event ID 2 from source PHP-7.4.5 cannot be found

Tags: php, windows, apache

I recently moved to another server and moved my PHP logs to the Windows event viewer. Since, I have been getting these information events:

"The description for Event ID 2 from source PHP-7.4.5 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer."

These occur when using PHPMailer which by itself works fine, so I don't see reason for alarm.

Is there a way to disable these events?

Comment: Look at the "Details" tab for that event and choose "XML View" and in the `<EventData>`-tag and you might find some more info about the event. If the code works as expected, I wouldn't care that much. The event logs in Windows tend to get _a lot_ of different "issues" on a regular basis. I've learned to only dig deeper if I actually have an issue with something.

Comment: I did that and it basically shows a summary from the mail sent (to, subject, from, that kind of information) but nothing of an error. If there is a way of not having these logs, these do include GDPR sensitive date after all.

Comment: I honestly don't know. However, that's a question that might be more suited over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) though since it's more of an server-admin question than a programming question.